# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting  syntax error, unexpected ''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /test/sms.php

the code for the sms.php is as follows

```
  <?php
$string = '<pushsms><Title>Test XML</Title></pushsms>';
$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Connection: close",
);


$xmlData = '
<pushsms>
<username>XXXXX</username>
<password>XXXXX</password>
<senderid>XXXXX</senderid>
<messages>
<message pno="1234567890" msg="Test sms from 1234567890. Thanks for choosing our service - XXXXX">
</message>
<message pno="1234567890" msg="Test sms from 1234567890. Thanks for choosing our service - XXXXX">
</message>
</messages>
</pushsms>';
$post = 'xmlstring='. urlencode($xmlData);
$url = "http://smsc.biz/xmlapi/send";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: When I run that exact code I get no errors at all

Comment: There is no error in your code. Please share full code.

Comment: @Gustaf
I'm getting this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''<pushsms><Title>TestÂ XML</Ti' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /test/sms.php on line 2

Comment: @Ankii Gangrade
I'm getting this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''<pushsms><Title>TestÂ XML</Ti' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /test/sms.php on line 2

Comment: @AdarshRaveendra It's something going on with the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to rewrite the space in

```
$string = '<pushsms><Title>Test XML</Title></pushsms>';
```

You have probably copied from somewhere else making it not really a space. So place your marker after "Test " and remove the space and then press space again.

So when copying from internet/other applications, be careful, otherwise problems like these may occur.

Comment: Yes, I the problem was with the spaces, so I typed the entire lines again.. thanks